# How to get values from Range Slider in JQuery - IonRangeSlider?

Tags: jquery, slider, rangeslider

how can I get the values from ion.rangeSlider component by change slider?

This is my jQuery code:

```
function rangeSlider() {
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");
$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
   // from: 0,
    grid: true,
```

});
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use build in callbacks to do that (`onChange, onStart, onFinish`): http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/gefkwqv6/

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
    $inputFrom = $(".js-input-from"),
    $inputTo = $(".js-input-to"),
    instance,
    min = 0,
    max = 1000;

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    min: min,
    max: max,
    from: 100,
    to: 900,
    onStart: updateInputs,
    onChange: updateInputs,
    onFinish: updateInputs
});

function updateInputs (data) {
    $inputFrom.prop("value", data.from);
    $inputTo.prop("value", data.to);
}

instance = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");
```